# jQueries validation plugin shows always on input

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm stuck with jQueries validation plugin

My input give me always an error. Code can you find here: http://jsfiddle.net/OrangeTux/6zUMd/1/

I want to create some custom rules, like postalcode, phonenumber and some other specific numbers. Therefore, I create a new method for the regular expression rule. This rule works correctly.

```
$.validator.addMethod("regexp", function(value, element, param) {
     return this.optional(element) || !param.test(value);
});
```

After that I create a new method:

`jQuery.validator.addMethod('postalCode', function(value, element) {});`

Then I use create a new class and add the rules

```
//add validation rules for each custom method
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
   postalCode: {
      'postalCode' : true,

       //regexp: /[^[0-9]{10}$]/, //<---- This regex doesn't work
       //email: true              // <----- This rule doens't work either
   }
})
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You haven't defined an implementation for the `postalCode` rule... What do you want/expect it to do?

Comment: I want it to check if the input of fields with class="postalcode" matches with the regexp (regexp: /[^[0-9]{10}$]/). And if the input doens't match the regexp, i want to show an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few things a bit backwards. First of all, the `regex` rule is not quite right. You want to return `true` from the method when the rule passes, so you should return:

```
return this.optional(element) || param.test(value);
```

Beyond that though, the preferred way for adding a custom rule like this is to use `addMethod`, and then `addClassRules` to add a class rule that includes that method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("postalCode", function (value, element, params) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9]{10}$/.test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid Postal Code");

//add validation rules for each custom method
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
    postalCode: {
        postalCode: true
   }
});

$("#form").validate({
    debug: true,

    //set place were error is shown
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo(element.parent("td").next("td"));
    },
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/LCA9C/

Comment: Nice, this works. A followup question. I want this field to be required. But when i add 'required: true' to the addClassRules method, it shows only the error message thats connected to the required rule: 'Please, give some data'. Is there a way that I can show the messages of 2 rules?